# Best way to store data in a spreadsheet application in java

Tags: java, serialization, jdbc

I am creating a spreadsheet application in Java programming language. I need to save my spreadsheets to open later when needed. So, what is the most suitable way to do this? Is it more suitable to use serialization in Java? Or is it suitable to create a database and use JDBC?What are the pros and cons of using these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Apache's POI library](http://poi.apache.org/) which can read and write .xls and .xlsx formatted files